# How can I download a binary file using Python and WinHTTPRequest?

Tags: python, win32com, winhttprequest

I need to download a bunch of pdf files from the web. I usually use the urllib3 library, but it is a corporate website with authentication. I can download a normal html web using the following:

```python
url = 'https://corpweb.example/index.html'
h = win32com.client.Dispatch('WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1')
h.SetAutoLogonPolicy(0)
h.Open('GET', url, False)
h.Send()
result = h.responseText
```

But this solution doesn't works with a PDF.

```python
url = "https://corpweb.example/file.pdf"
h = win32com.client.Dispatch('WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1')
h.SetAutoLogonPolicy(0)
h.Open('GET', url, False)
h.Send()
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(h.responseText)
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

As Microsoft’s documentation of [`WinHttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest) explains, [`responseText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-responsetext) contains the response body as Unicode text. To obtain the response body as raw bytes, use [`responseBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-responsebody) instead.

Also consider using [`responseStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-responsestream) instead of either, to avoid keeping the entire file in memory at once.

Answer (score -1):

Try using urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filepath)?

```py
import urllib.request as url
url="https://corpweb/file.pdf"
url.urlretrieve(url, "file.pdf")
```

It may be the best solution.
Or you can use requests:

```py
import requests
import os
url="https://corpweb/file.pdf"
resp = requests.get(url) # Get the response
os.system("type nul > file.pdf") # Create a new file
f = open("file.pdf", "wb") # Open file
f.write(resp.content) # Write
f.close() # Close file
```

Answer (score -2):

Open file Mode :

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    ...
```

This means that all data read from the file is returned as bytes objects, not str. You cannot then use a string in a containment test:

```
if 'some-pattern' in tmp:
    continue
```

Comment: I don't want to read from the file. I want to save the pdf from the web server to my local drive.